# How to add IHttpContextAccessor to AuthorizationHandler

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to write an authorization attribute, with an httpContext.

```
 public class AuthorizationCheck : AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizationCheck>, IAuthorizationRequirement
        {
    
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
            public AuthorizationCheck(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
    }
    
          services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

     services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizationCheck>();
    
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AuthorizationCheck",
                    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizationCheck()));
            });
```

My problem is that I get this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
> parameter 'httpContextAccessor' of
> 'AuthorizationCheck.AuthorizationCheck(IHttpContextAccessor)'

Comment: You need to call `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` where your registering your services.

Comment: @asawyer Thanks, but I have already have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building your authorization policy incorrectly. According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#requirements), you should be adding an additional class that also inherits `IAuthorizationRequirement` and then on your `AuthorizationCheck` the generic type parameter should be that additional class. Example below:

```
public class AuthorizationCheck : AuthorizationHandler<IsAdminRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
        {
    
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
            public AuthorizationCheck(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
    }

public class IsAdminRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Finally, when adding your policy you'd add the `IsAdminRequirement`. Note that this requirement should only hold data/logic necessary to the requirement - the actual handler, `AuthorizationCheck` should contain your dependency injection that performs actions on the requirement.